# Unable to re-use members of base clas

Tags: c#

Below is my code snippet.
My need is that i want to re-use member of base class in the multiple derived classes.
But m getting error
What i'm doing wrong here ?

```
public class A
{
    public int Num1;
    public int Num2;
    public int Num3;
    public int Num4;
}

public class B:A { // As it is inherting from base class A it should have access to base members
    //A ac = new A();
    Num1 = 1; // I'm getting error this fields does not exist in current context. How can i make re-use of class A members ?
    Num2 = 2;
    Num3 = 3;
    Num4 = 4;
}
public class C : A
{

    Num1 = 1;
    Num2 = 2;
    Num3 = 3;
    Num4 = 4;
}
```

Comment: You need to assign the values in a constructor.

Comment: That code must sit in the scope of a function.

Comment: You can assign a value during deceleration, but to assign a value after deceleration you would have to do that in a constructor or a method of the class.  Ultimately what are you trying to accomplish though?  This really seems like a bad design.

Comment: this is simply invalid syntax, nothing to do with accessibility

Comment: @maccettura actually i have few classes where i have 50 fields are the same.
So i thought instead of creating 50 fields in every class i should create this in one base class and re-use them in my all respective derived classes from the base one.

Comment: @SureshRajput You have classes that all have the same 50 fields?  With the same exact values?

Comment: @maccettura yes fields are the same but values can be different as per the logic of every derived class.

Comment: Are they constant values?  Meaning are they allowed to change after the object has been created?

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid syntax.

You mean

```
    public class C : A
    {
        public C()
       {
          Num1 = 1;
          Num2 = 2;
          Num3 = 3;
          Num4 = 4;
      }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't declare a variable in `A` if you do not initialise it.

But you could make `A` abstract and use Properties for that:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract int Num1 { get; }
}

public class B:A {
    public override int Num1 { get; } = 1;
}
```

Comment: An even simpler syntax exists: `public override int Num1 => 1;`

Comment: @BlueMonkMN That's not a simpler syntax, that's a radically different behavior, and almost certainly not a desirable one.

Comment: @Servy "almost certainly not a desirable one"  Please explain.

Comment: @Servy why it the syntax `=>` not equal?

Comment: @Amy The OP has defined public fields and attempted to initialize them to a given value.  This provides code that has properties with no setter, no backing field, and that always provide a fixed value.  That's radically different.  The OP provided no indication that they want properties that always return a constant value.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough, and I agree.  This is not the desired behavior from the question.

Comment: @fab It's defining the implementation of a getter, rather than an initial value for an automatically implemented property.

Comment: @Amy okay: I agree, too. The syntax `public override int Num1 { get; } = 1` is better.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN And yet they're still different.  And [I've already explained the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268818/unable-to-re-use-members-of-base-clas/48268943?noredirect=1#comment83521179_48268943).  So again, it's not a "simpler syntax" to do the same thing.  It's code that *does a completely different thing*.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Since apparently you can't follow a link, or read a comment posted earlier in this same post, I guess I'll just repeat myself.  The answer suggested using an automatically implemented property with an initializer initializing it to a fixed value, you suggested creating a property with a user defined getter that simply returns a fixed value.  *That's a different behavior*, and not just a different syntax for doing the same thing.  That neither do what the OP is asking doesn't mean that one is just a different syntax for implementing the other.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Yes, there's a backing field for an auto property.  You can get or set the value in the constructor.  It also determines whether the expression you're using is performed each time the property getter is called or only once and then stored in the backing field.

Comment: @Servy I forgot or wasn't aware that values of auto properties without setters could be initialized in the constructor. So I shouldn't have used the term "syntax" since the difference is a little deeper than syntax. Still it's not clear from the context of the OP which solution makes more sense (if either do). If the value is constant, it may make sense to use the shorter version to avoid the need to allocate space for every instance. In the case of the constants in the OP I would be surprised if the compiled code actually does more work in evaluating the "expression" each time for a constant.